# Access all the fields in a Lists using powershell,SharePoint and csom

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to retrieve all the items in my list and for each item display the Title of the item,ID and created fields on the console. Also when I do a `get-member` on the Items collection I don't see all the fields in the list (not even the title field, only the ID and some other fields that I don't believe are used very much like `DisplayName`)

I would have thought that the `caml` query will only select the fields to show, but none of the items I specified on my `Caml` query are showing on `get-Member`

Please can anybody help spot what I may be doing wrong

```html
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,$Password)
{
    #$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Password)
    return $context
}

Function Get-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
    $qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery(13,'ID','Created','Modified','Title')
    $items = $list.GetItems($qry)
    $Context.Load($items)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    return $items 
}

$UserName = "john.doe@sharepointonline.co.uk"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString    
$Url = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/COP/SharePoint/john"

$context = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$items = Get-ListItems -Context $context -ListTitle "NPT Form" 

foreach($item in $items)
{
   $item.Id
   $item | gm
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close on not doing anything wrong. The properties you are looking for are actually stored in the dictionary `FieldValues`. This will be listed when you perform `get-member` on the Items collection.

The proprieties can be listed using:

```
$item.FieldValues
```

And can be accessed using the following methods, for Title:

```
$item["Title"]
$item.FieldsValues.Title
```